# Matter.js Bodies bouncing even with restitution set to 0

Tags: javascript, matter.js, restitution

I am making a game called Perfectly Balanced (it's based off an iWatch game) and I'm using Matter.js

The problem is that when you press space/click to drop the body, if there are already some bodies on the ground, they bounce and fall apart.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried setting all of the bodies (except for the ground) restitution to `0`, but it still bounces.

The code can be found [here](https://perfectly-balanced.luisafk.repl.co/)

```js
// HTML elements
const container = document.querySelector('div#container');

// module aliases
let Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Composite = Matter.Composite,
    Events = Matter.Events;

// create an engine
let engine = Engine.create();
engine.world.gravity.y *= 1;
engine.velocityIterations = 6;
engine.positionIterations = 10;
engine.constraintIterations = 8;

// create a renderer
let render = Render.create({
  element: container,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    wireframes: false,
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    background: 'cyan',
    hasBounds: true
  }
});

// create ground
let ground = Bodies.rectangle(render.options.width / 2, render.options.height - 10, render.options.width - 10, 10, {
  isStatic: true,
  render: {
    fillStyle: 'white'
  }
});

let current = 0;
let score = 0;
let step = 1;

let camera_y = 0;

// add all of the bodies to the world
Composite.add(engine.world, ground);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

// create runner
let runner = Runner.create();

// run the engine
Runner.run(runner, engine);

// before tick
Events.on(runner, "beforeTick", () => {
  if (typeof current == 'number')
  {
    current++;

    if (current >= 30)
    {
      if (step == 3)
      {
        current = Bodies.rectangle(20, 35, Math.random() * 100 + 80, 10);
        //Body.setMass(current, current.mass * 2);
      }
      else
      {
        current = Bodies.rectangle(20, 35, 30, 60);
        //Body.setMass(current, current.mass / 2);
      }
  
      step++;
  
      if (step >= 4)
        step = 1;
  
      Body.setStatic(current, true);
  
      if (!current.render)
        current.render = {};
  
      current.render.fillStyle = 'white';

      Body.setMass(current, 1);

      current.friction = 1;
      current.frictionAir = 0;
      current.frictionStatic = 100;
      current.restitution = 0;
      current.slop = 0.8;
      current.inertia = 100;
      current.inverseInertia = 1 / current.inertia;
  
      Composite.add(engine.world, current);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (!current._dir)
      current._dir = 1;
  
    if (current._dir == 1 && current.position.x >= render.options.width - 20)
      current._dir = -1;
    else if (current._dir == -1 && current.position.x <= 20)
      current._dir = 1;
  
    Body.setPosition(current, {
      x: current.position.x + 2 * current._dir,
      y: current.position.y
    });
  }
});

// after tick
Events.on(runner, "afterTick", () => {
  // draw score
  render.context.font = '30px Arial';
  render.context.fillText(score, 5, 30);

  // move camera
  render.bounds.min.y = camera_y;
  render.bounds.max.y = camera_y + render.options.height;

  // death
  
});

// on space
const clickHandler = e => {
  if (
    typeof current != 'number' && (
      (e.type == 'keydown' && e.code == 'Space') ||
      (e.type == 'touchstart') ||
      (e.type == 'mousedown')
    )
  )
  {
    Body.setStatic(current, false);
    Body.setAngularVelocity(current, 0);
    Body.setVelocity(current, { x: 0, y: 0 });
    
    current = 0;

    score++;
  }
};
window.addEventListener('keydown', clickHandler);
render.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', clickHandler);
render.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', clickHandler);

// on window resize
const resizeHandler = e => {
  if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight)
  {
    container.style.width = '100vw';
    container.style.height = 'auto';
  }
  else
  {
    container.style.width = 'auto';
    container.style.height = '100vh';
  }
};
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
resizeHandler();
```

```css
body
{
  margin: 0px;

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div#container
{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Perfectly Balanced</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.18.0/matter.min.js" integrity="sha512-5T245ZTH0m0RfONiFm2NF0zcYcmAuNzcGyPSQ18j8Bs5Pbfhp5HP1hosrR8XRt5M3kSRqzjNMYpm2+it/AUX/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ggorlen The code is posted now. If you place two bricks near each other and a platform on top (like a bridge) and drop another brick on top, it bounces even though all bodies's restitution is set to 0

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So it seems like you'd want to set the bodies static when they hit the ground, otherwise they will move and react when struck. What's the objective of the game?

Comment: @ggorlen You want to get as high as possible without anything falling (Perfectly Balanced). And I can't make them static because I need them to be able to fall if you place something in an _unbalanced position_